# Como imprimir um relatório RDLC no asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer, relatório

Tenho o *rdlc* criado, e tenho uma pagina `aspx` que tem um botão imprimir, ao clicar em imprimir quero chamar o *rdlc* que tenho criado para impressão. Como faço?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O botão Imprimir deve chamar outro aspx. Neste aspx, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report.rdlc");
        var dsClientes = GetData("select top 20 * from clientes");
        ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("Clientes", dsClientes.Tables[0]);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
    }
}

private Customers GetData(string query)
{
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;

            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (Customers dsClientes = new Customers())
            {
                sda.Fill(dsClientes, "DataTable1");
                return dsClientes;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Tirei o exemplo daqui](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/RDLC-Local-SSRS-Report-ASPNet-Example-using-DataSet-or-DataTable-in-C-VBNet-and-Visual-Studio-2010.aspx).

Comment: Eu vi esse exemplo, porem aqui nao encontra nada de reportView ao digitar

Comment: Você adicionou o componente `ReportViewer1` no aspx conforme o exemplo?

Comment: esse reportview se referencia a q? classe?

Comment: Componente `ReportViewer`, seção *Reporting* da barra de componentes que fica à esquerda. Tem esta parte no exemplo.

Comment: Eu apenas digitei     <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Width="600">

Comment: Deu certo aqui, vou testar